# R Studio time series, "X has to be numeric"

Tags: r, time-series

I created a time series in R Studio, where I try to analyse the CO2 emissions of the United States. I created a time series of the CO2 emissions and plotted it, which worked very well.

After that I tried to apply the `acf()` and `pacf()` functions, but R is saying that there is a mistake bec. "x has to be numeric". I don't unterstand why bec. I just have numeric values in my time series data set.

```
CHemission <- ts(dfCH$Emission, start = 1960, frequency = 1) #create a time series of the emission
plot(CHemission) # plot it
acf(CHemission) # apply acf, which unfortunately does not work.
```

Thank you much in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Hi, it seems that the problem is related to your data. Could you please copy/paste the result of  `dput(CHemission)`, or, better, the output of `dput(dfCH)` in your question? If the dataset is too big, you could use `dput(head(dfCH))`. This will help making your [example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: structure(c("780726.3", "552066.8", "440359", "436695.7", "436923", 
"475972.9", "522789.5", "433234", "468928.6", "577237.1", "771617.5", 
"876633", "931575.7", "968542.7", "988014.5", "1145607", "1196194", 
"1310311", "1462169", "1494860", "1467192", "1451501", "1580261", 
"1667029", "1814908", "1966553", "2068969", "2209709", "2369502", 
"2408541", "2173360", "2302190", "2418180", "2643530", "2763900", 
"), .Tsp = c(1960, 2016, 
1), class = "ts")

Comment: Thanks for the data, unfortunately it does not produce usable object. They might be typos in the data you copy/pasted. For ex, there is `, ")` and even if I remove it is says that this is not enough to make a time serie object...